# limit of getting entities in telegram api

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I want to parse all tg channel commentators, there is my code:

```
    async def getCommentators(self, channelName):
        print('started')
        async with self.client as client:
            async with client.takeout(users=True,channels=True,chats=True,contacts=True,megagroups=True) as takeout:
                channelEntity = await self.client.get_entity(channelName)
                commentators = set()
                start_time = time.time()
                async for post in takeout.iter_messages(channelEntity,limit=2):
                    if not isinstance(post, types.Message):
                        continue
                    try:
                        async for comment in takeout.iter_messages(post.peer_id, reply_to=int(post.id)):
                            if hasattr(comment,'from_id'):
                                if isinstance(comment.from_id,types.PeerUser):
                                    commentators.add(comment.from_id.user_id)
                                    print(comment.from_id.user_id)
                    except errors.rpcerrorlist.MsgIdInvalidError:
                        print('error')
                listOfCommentators = []
                for commentator in commentators:
                    user = await takeout.get_entity(commentator)
                    if user.username:
                        username = user.username
                    elif user.usernames:
                        if len(user.usernames) > 0:
                            username = user.usernames[0]
                        else:
                            username = user.id
                    else:
                        username = user.id
                    listOfCommentators.append(
                        (
                            username,
                            user.phone if user.phone else "",
                            self.getStatus(user.status) if user.status else '',
                            user.premium if user.premium else '',
                            user.first_name if user.first_name else '',
                            user.last_name if user.last_name else "",
                            Genderize().get(username)[0].get('gender') if isinstance(username,str) else ''
                        )
                    )
                end_time = time.time()
                print(f'{start_time - end_time}')
                return listOfCommentators, channelEntity.username if channelEntity.username else channelEntity.usernames[0]
```

When it comes to the second for loop(where I'm collecting commentator's data) and there is an attempt to get the user's entity(user = await takeout.get_entity(commentator)), I get error:

```
genderize.GenderizeException: ('Request limit too low to process request', 429, {'Server': 'nginx/1.16.1', 'Date': 'Tue, 07 Nov 2023 12:35:20 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '52', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-rate-limit-limit,x-rate-limit-remaining,x-rate-limit-reset', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate', 'x-rate-limit-limit': '1000', 'x-rate-limit-remaining': '1', 'x-rate-limit-reset': '41080', 'x-request-id': 'id'})
```

I tried to add asyncio.sleep(5) in the loop, but it doesn't seem to help, the error still apears(or may be I should've done this before I reached my limits)

As I understand I have 1000 requests limit for getting user entities per day.
Any ideas how to avoid this?
Or maybe any ideas how to get user's username, phone, first_name without getting the entity?

Answer (score 0):

Getting entities is least punished when you and the entity have something in common. For example you are both in the same group and members of the group are visible for all. client.get_entity() is therefore most punished if you have nothing in common because it is marked as spam or data scraping.

If you have a group in common you want to use client.get_participants(groupname, search=username) to get the entities info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).